# Why are the formatted currency amounts from my Sheet being replaced incorrectly in Documents table using .replaceText() in Appscript?

Tags: google-sheets, merge, formatting, google-docs

Using Appscript to merge data from Google Sheet to a table in Google Doc template. I am using body.replaceText() and its working but its dropping the decimal places in some data or adding two more in others. The data is coming from an invoice template and going to a contract template. It is formatted as currency with two decimal places in Sheets, but shows up with either no decimal places or 4 decimal places

```
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody(); 
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet
    const tables=body.getTables();
    body.replaceText('{{Name}}', firstAndLastName);
    body.replaceText('{{Address}}', address);
    body.replaceText('{{CityStateZip}}', cityState);
    body.replaceText('{{Email}}', email);
    body.replaceText('{{Phone}}', phone);
    body.replaceText('{{Line1}}', line1);
    body.replaceText('{{Line2}}', line2);
    body.replaceText('{{Line3}}', line3);
    body.replaceText('{{Line4}}', line4);
    body.replaceText('{{Line5}}', line5);
    body.replaceText('{{Line1Total}}', line1Total);
    body.replaceText('{{Line2Total}}', line2Total);
    body.replaceText('{{Line3Total}}', line3Total);
    body.replaceText('{{Line4Total}}', line4Total);
    body.replaceText('{{Line5Total}}', line5Total);
    body.replaceText('{{SubTotal}}',subTotal);
    body.replaceText('{{Tax}}', tax);
    body.replaceText('{{Total}}', total);
        
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVsBB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZVfJ.png)

I tried looking through the apprscript docs services https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute to find something for formatting once is gets to Document but I can't seem to find anything regarding text formatting. I also played around with Sheets formatting the decimal places but that didn't help either.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see your whole script. But, from `It is formatted as currency with two decimal places in Sheets`, if you are retrieving the values from Google Spreadsheet using `getValues()`, please modify `getValues()` to `getDisplayValues()` and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()) But, I cannot know your actual situation. When this was not the direct solution to your current issue, I apologize.

Comment: That worked like a charm. You're Awesome! Can you explain to me what exactly this is doing?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `That worked like a charm. You're Awesome!`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I flagged it as a duplicate question. About `Can you explain to me what exactly this is doing?`, the official document of `getDisplayValues` says `Returns the rectangular grid of values for this range.`. By this, the formatted values on the cells could be directly retrieved.